# mysql select replace function

Tags: mysql, replace

I have this problem. I have two tables from which I want to extrapolate the values, specifically in a field of a table are the ids of the second table separated by;
Using this procedure:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM tab1
 WHERE id in (SELECT REPLACE(field,";",",") as idresult 
                from tab2 
               where tab2.id=1)
```

From this query I expect more rows because in the tab2 field there are these values (1;2;3;4;5)

If the same procedure you run without Select Replace I get the correct 
results ie::

```
SELECT name FROM tab1
WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

it's right. Should I use the replacement you have suggestions?

Comment: You could use FIND_IN_SET for this, but normalisation is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your `WHERE` clause: `in` is used to compare between a value and vector of values (column). In your case you check if `tab1.id` is equal to at least one of results of `idresult`.

**But** `idresult` is just a column of **strings** - now with **,** inside instead of **;** after the replacement.

You can use [MySQL locate function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php) in order to find if there is a substring in a string:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM tab1, tab2
 WHERE LOCATE(tab2.id, tab2.field)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding is that tab2 query will provide you the comma seperated string which should be used as filter in tab1. For this you can use the FIND_IN_SET command in MySQL as given below:

```
select name from tab1 where find_in_set( id, (SELECT REPLACE(field,";",",") from tab2 where tab2.id=1)) > 0;
```